# How to use useNavigate in combination with useEffect in React component to conditionally redirect when component renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my "main" component (the one that is cointaining my "router" and all my "routes") I would like to fetch the currently logged in user from my "backend".

Then I would either store this user in my global "context" (to make them accessible from all "pages", allow to protect certain "routes", etc.) if there is one, or I would like to redirect to my "login page" (see `switch` statement in the sample code below) if there is no user currently logged in.

However, that does not work since `navigate()` appears to work only if the call to it originates from within the `<Router>` component. Is there a simple and "best-practice" way to solve this? Any hint or idea is highly appreciated! Thanks!

```ts
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { User, Context, UserContext } from '../lib/UserContext';
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Test from '../pages/Test';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import Register from '../pages/Register';
import axios from 'axios';
const StatusCodes = require('../statusCodes');

const AppRouter = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const context = useMemo<Context>(
    () => ({ user: user, setUser: setUser }),
    [user, setUser]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      withCredentials: true,
      url: 'http://localhost:4000/user',
    }).then((res) => {
      switch (res.data.code) {
        case StatusCodes.UserIsLoggedIn:
          console.log('A user is logged in. Context set to this user.');
          context.setUser({
            lastName: res.data.user.lastName,
            firstName: res.data.user.firstName,
            email: res.data.user.email,
            role: res.data.user.role,
          });
          break;
        case StatusCodes.NoUserIsLoggedIn:
          console.log('No user is logged in. Redirect to login page.');
          navigate('/login');
          break;
        default:
          console.log('Status code not recognized. Redirect to test page.');
          navigate('/test');
          break;
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={context}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple and "best-practice" way to solve this?

Yes! You can move the `Router` higher in the ReactTree... higher than the component you want to use the `navigate` function ***and*** provide a Context value you want to update.

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const context = useMemo<Context>(
    () => ({ user: user, setUser: setUser }),
    [user, setUser]
  );

  ...

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={context}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
      </Routes>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

...

```
<Router>
  <AppRouter />
</Router>
```